# Counting occurrences in a list with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a custom class, PDFDataItem, providing the getValue() method which returns a double value (see the attached code).
I also have an ArrayList of several PDFDataItem instances, each one with a specific value: different instances can have the same value.
What I would like to do is to create a LinkedHashMap where to store, univocally, the values of the instances and, for each value found, the number of occurencies (i.e. the number of instances in which it compares).
Of course, I can find lots of tricks to reach my goal, but I'd like to know if a quick method (possibly using lambda) exists.

```
public class PDFDataItem{

    double value;

    public PDFDataItem(double value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public double getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why it has to be a `LinkedHashMap`? By the way, equality and `double` values are not good friends. You should rethink either, the task or the chosen data type.

Comment: @Holger no specific reason. I felt confident with a Map and I thought of a LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a `Stream<PDFDataItem>` with `Collectors.groupingBy()` `Collector` to group the `PDFDataItem` instances by the `value` property and then count the number of elements in each group using the `Collectors.counting()` `Collector`.

```
Map<Double,Long> valueCounts = 
    pdfList.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PDFDataItem::getValue,Collectors.counting()));
```